# Yii2: Is there a Yii-way to force the browser reloading a CSS file?

Tags: caching, yii2, browser-cache, yii2-advanced-app

Normally I would just do something like this:

```
<link href="main.css?<?= filemtime($file) ?>">
```

Is there a better way in Yii? – If not, is there a way I can add this to $this->head() for a specific CSS file?

Comment: You are trying to use a different layout for each view, is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are properly using asset bundles to load your styles you can set [`yii\web\AssetManager::$appendTimestamp`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetmanager#$appendTimestamp-detail) property of asset manager component to append timestamp automatically.

You can do that in your app config file (for example `frontend/config/main.php`):

```php
return [
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'appendTimestamp' => true,
        ],
    ],
    // ... other configurations ...
]
```

See [the guide article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets) for more info about asset bundles.